# Mongo Query on Subfields

Tags: mongodb

I have a document -

> ```
>   {"_id" : ObjectId("51385d2308d427ce306f0100"),
>   "aid" : "1",
>   "studyId" : "study-1",
>   "mediaType" : "microBlog",
>   "text" : "bla bla",
>   "sentences" : "bla bla",
>   "status" : {
>           "algo1" : "required",
>           "algo2" : "required",
>           "algo3" : "completed",
>           "algo4" : "completed"
>   },
>   "priority" : "u"}
> ```

The status field has multiple sub-fields with different status values. Is it possible to create a query such that it returns all documents for which any of the status sub-field's value is "required"?

Something like `db.foo.find({status : "required"})` which would give me all documents for which any of the sub-field has value "required"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another, more efficient, approach would be to implement your "status" sub-document as an array of "typed values", like this:

```
 {"_id" : ObjectId("51385d2308d427ce306f0100"),
  "aid" : "1",
  "studyId" : "study-1",
  "mediaType" : "microBlog",
  "text" : "bla bla",
  "sentences" : "bla bla",
  "status" : [
          { type: "algo1", value: "required" },
          { type: "algo2", value: "required" },
          { type: "algo3", value: "completed" },
          { type: "algo4", value: "completed" }
  ],
  "priority" : "u"}
```

This would allow you to find all the documents, for which any of the sub-field has value "required", with this query:

```
db.foo.find({"status.value":"required"})
```

Defining an index on this sub-field would speed up the query:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({"status.value":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

u could search via `db.foo.find({ 'status.algo1' : 'required' })` or `db.foo.find({ 'status.algo2' : 'required' })`, but it's probably not possible to filter by regex `keys`, see also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290728/654952

Comment: Yes, I would need to use or conditions for each status.algo as what I require is not possible in Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [mapReduce()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce) where the map() function would contain something like:

```
// loop all key/value pairs in status without knowing its key
for ( item in this.status ) {
    // if value is required: emit the data and break the loop
    if ( this.status[item] == "required" ) {
        emit( ... )
        break;
    }
}
```

does this help ?

Cheers

Ronald