# In MongoDB, when to use a simple subdocument, when an array with 2-field elements?

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

### Background

I am storing table rows as MongoDb documents, with each column having a name. Let's say table has these columns of interest: `Identifier`, `Person`, `Date`, `Count`. The MongoDb document also has some extra fields separate from the table data, represented by `timestamp`. Columns are not fixed (which is why I use schema-free database to store them in the first place).

There will be need to do various complex, but so far unspecified queries. I am not very concerned about performance, though query performance may conceivably become a bottleneck. Once inserted, documents will not be modifed (a new document with same `Identifier` will be created instead), and insertions are not very frequent (let's say, 1000 new MongoDb documents per day). So amount of data will steadily grow over time.

### Example

The straight-forward approach is having a collection of MongoDb documents like:

```
{
   _id: XXXX,
   insertDate: ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z"),
   flag: true,
   data: {
       Identifier: "AB002",
       Person: "John002",
       Date: ISODate("2013-11-16T21:26:17Z"),
       Count: 1
   }
}
```

Now I have seen an alternative approach (for example in accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268063/mongo-query-on-subfields)), using array with two fields per object:

```
{
   _id: XXXX,
   insertDate: ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z"),
   flag: true,
   data: [
       { field: "Identifier", value: "AB002" },
       { field: "Person", value: "John001" },
       { field: "Date", value: ISODate("2013-11-16T21:26:17Z") },
       { field: "Count", value: 1 }
   ]
}
```

### Questions

Does the 2nd approach make any sense at all?

If yes, then how to choose which to use? Especially, are there some specific kinds of queries which are easy/cheap with one approach, hard/costly with another? Any "rules of thumb" on which way to go, or pro-con lists for both? Example real-life cases of one aproach being inconvenient would be especially valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example the First version is a lot more appropriate and simple. You have to think in terms of how you would query your document.

It is a lot simpler to query your database like this: `db.collection.find({"data.Identifier": "AB002"})`

Although I'm not 100% sure why you even need the inner document. Why can't structure your document like:

```
{
   _id:  "AB002",
   insertDate: ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z"),
   flag: true,
   Person: "John002",
   Date: ISODate("2013-11-16T21:26:17Z"),
   Count: 1
}
```

**Pros of first example:**

- Simple to query
- Enforces unique keys, but your data won't have two columns with the same name anyway
- I would assume mongoDB would generate better query plans because the structure is a lot more simple (haven't tested)

**Pros of second example:**

- Allows multiple entries with the same key/field, but I don't feel that is useful in your case
- A single index on the array can be used for all of its entries regardless of their field name

Comment: The reason to put them to subdocument is, that exact fields in the subdocument are not fixed, and I still want to be able to grab them all with `aggregate` (not sure if there's a workaround for this). Another reason is to prevent future name conflicts (for example if some subdocument has `flag` field).

Comment: @hyde, that makes sense. Out of interest, is the insertDate the time it was inserted into mongoDB or into the original table?

Comment: *insertDate* is conceptually the time when a change in original data was detected, but (at least for now) effectively time when document was inserted to MongoDB collection. same info could be extracted from *_id* I think, but explicit field seems clearer and more flexible towards unknown future requirements.

Comment: Oh okay, I was just going to mention that the time is embedded in the `_id` but you already know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the situation in the other example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268063/mongo-query-on-subfields) and yours are the same. In the other example, they're creating a list of items with one of two answers, which would be more appropriately in an array, and the goal is to return a list of subdocuments that match the criteria. In your example, you're really just describing an object since they all hold different types of information, and you won't need to retrieve searchable bits of the subdocuments.