# Mongodb find all records where subfields in a given set in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a Document that looks like this
`{
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":{"unknown_key1":"value2",
                  "unknown_key2":"value3",
                  ...
                  "unknown_keyN":"valueN"}
}`

and an array("arr1","arr2","arr3")

I want to query to find all documents where all of the unknown keys are in the set defined by my array, except the number N of these keys and their value is unknown. is this possible in Mongodb and if so how would I go about doing it.

Comment: is your array contains this array("unknown_key1","unknown_key2",....,""unknown_keyN")?

Comment: No my array contains other keys I want to find all documents where all the unknown keys are one of those other keys in the array

Comment: It means some of unknown keys presents in array right?

Comment: im trying to query to find out if they are in the array, i don't know if they are necessarily

Comment: It's poor data modeling to use data as keys or to have "unknown" keys. Alternatively, you could make each unknown_key, value pair into an object `{ "key" : "unknown_key", "value" : "value" }` and have `field2` be an array of these objects. In that case you should look at [this old SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per your questions I think some number of unknown_key presents in your array suppose if your array contains following values,

```
var values = ("arr1","arr2","arr3",..."unknown_key1","unknown_key2",.."arrN")
```

If it right  then you should use following query to find out

```
for( i = 0; i < values.length ; i++ ) {
db.collectionName.find({},{"field2."+values[i]:1})
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with PHP but what you normally do in other languages is using an array of objects and then use subnotation for this.

E.g:

```
"field1":"value1",
"field2":[
    {"unknown_key1":"value2"},
    {"unknown_key2":"value3"}
     ...
    {"unknown_keyN":"valueN"}
    ]
```

Then you can find them by

```
...find({"field2.unknown_key1": "value2", ... })
```

See another example here [Mongo Query on Subfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268063/mongo-query-on-subfields)

Comment: How can I do find of field2.unknown_key1 when I don't know what unknown_key1 is though

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$where` in this case. If any of the unknown keys should be in the set defined by the array:

```
db.collection_name.find({$where: function() {
  var myarr = ["unknown_key", "arr1", "arr2", "arr3"];
  for(var key in this.field2) {
    var subkey = key.substr(0, key.length-1); //get unknown_key from unknown_keyN
    var id = myarr.indexOf(subkey); // check if in array 
    if (id != -1) return true;
  }
  return false;
}})
```

If all of the unknown keys should be in the set defined by the array:

```
db.collection_name.find({$where: function() {
  var myarr = ["unknown_key", "arr1", "arr2", "arr3"];
  if (this.field2  != undefined) {
    for(var key in this.field2) {
      var subkey = key.substr(0, key.length-1); //get unknown_key from unknown_keyN
      var id = myarr.indexOf(subkey); // check if in array 
      if (id == -1) return false;
    } 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}})
```

Comment: $where queries can be very slow. Its better to change the document to meet a better search query