# Can you combine specific and none-specific fields in mongodb find on embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have embedded documents like

```
{ a: 
     { aa: { aaa: 1, bbb: 2, ccc: 3 },
       bb: { aaa: 1, bbb: 2, ccc: 3 },
       cc: { aaa: 1, bbb: 2, ccc: 3 }
     }
}
```

How can I write a field filter like:

```
find({}, { "a.*.aaa": 1 } )

* = aa, bb, cc
```

In mongodb documentation is no hint (see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you are querying for value. But what you are trying is on the key. We have to give exact match on the key.

We can use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to match on value and not on the key.

Let us have a collection

```
db.collection.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed6c911c8e111fb99bf4"), "name" : "a.aa.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed72911c8e111fb99bf5"), "name" : "a.bb.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed77911c8e111fb99bf6"), "name" : "a.bb.bbb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed7b911c8e111fb99bf7"), "name" : "a.cc.bbb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed7f911c8e111fb99bf8"), "name" : "a.cc.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed84911c8e111fb99bf9"), "name" : "a.cc.bbb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed88911c8e111fb99bfa"), "name" : "a.cc.ccc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed9a911c8e111fb99bfb"), "name" : "a.aa.ccc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eeda4911c8e111fb99bfc"), "name" : "a.aa.bbb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eedfd911c8e111fb99bfd"), "name" : "a.aa.abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eee03911c8e111fb99bfe"), "name" : "a.bb.abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eee06911c8e111fb99bff"), "name" : "a.cc.abc" }
```

Then the query using $regex is like

```
db.collection.find({name:{$regex: /a.*.aa*/}});
```

and the result of this query

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed6c911c8e111fb99bf4"), "name" : "a.aa.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed72911c8e111fb99bf5"), "name" : "a.bb.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed7f911c8e111fb99bf8"), "name" : "a.cc.aaa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eed9a911c8e111fb99bfb"), "name" : "a.aa.ccc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eeda4911c8e111fb99bfc"), "name" : "a.aa.bbb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eedfd911c8e111fb99bfd"), "name" : "a.aa.abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eee03911c8e111fb99bfe"), "name" : "a.bb.abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583eee06911c8e111fb99bff"), "name" : "a.cc.abc" }
```

Pls refer: [Mongodb - regex match of keys for subobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278417/mongodb-regex-match-of-keys-for-subobjects)

Hope it Helps!